# Twig template parent() caused double parent block

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I have a `base.html.twig` `template.html.twig` and `dashboard.html.twig`.
Dashboard extends template which extends base.

Base:

```
{% block javascripts %} 
    <script src="1.js"></script> 
{% endblock %}
```

Template:

```
{% block javascripts %} 
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="2.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Dashboard:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="3.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

This templating setup resulted in redundant script tags where everything is doubled like this

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
```

Am I missing something? Why is it happening?

Edit1:

base.html.twig:

```
extends nothing
```

template.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

default/dashboard.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::template.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Can you generate a minimum viable reproducible test case? There's not enough context in your example to see what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @jbafford I got rid of the issue by removing the `parent()` function call from the template.twig.html and by adding the scripts to the base. It's still not a solution.

Comment: What you describe should not be happening, given the examples you posted. Could there be anything else interfering?

Comment: @Yoshi Could the environment be badly set up? I'm working on a remote server and both ownership, group and permissions are set for app/cache app/logs and app/config/parameters.yml

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but since there's no accepted answer yet, I'll give it a go.

I was experiencing the same and this solved it for me, in my case it had to do with the structure of the base template and the current template from where you're trying to extend the base file, in my case, it was, in a similar situation as yours as far I can tell from your code.

Basically the structure in this example is wrong:

**base:**

```
{% block notAddedInTemplate %}
    {% block javascripts %} 
        <script src="1.js"></script> 
    {% endblock javascripts%}
{% endblock notAddedInTemplate %}
```

**Template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %} 
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="2.js"></script>
{% endblock javascripts%}
```

And should be:

**base:**

```
{% block notAddedInTemplate %}
    {% block javascripts %} 
        <script src="1.js"></script> 
    {% endblock javascripts%}
{% endblock notAddedInTemplate %}
```

**Template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block notAddedInTemplate %}
        {% block javascripts %} 
        {{ parent() }}
        <script src="2.js"></script>
    {% endblock notAddedInTemplate %}
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your `{% extends "file" %}` is bad.

The fix :

Template :

```
{% extends "base_path" %}
{% block javascripts %} 
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="2.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Dashboard :

```
{% extends "template_path" %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="3.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I added Edit1 to my original post. Does that look wrong?

Comment: Your code means good. Maybe verify you have not add the js in the head AND the footer.

Comment: No, I haven't added the blocks anywhere but at the end of the body.